# How to deselect single checked checkbox in multiselect widget?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, checkbox

I want to deselect checked checkbox in multiselect widget automatically. I am performing click event on checkbox of multiselect widget. And after clicking the checkbox I am sending request to php page through ajax for checking some result. If I got result successfully then I am simply giving alert to the user. And then after alert I want to deselect the checkbox automatically.I am provifing my code. 
This is my jquery code :

```
$("#multiselectunittype").multiselect("widget").on('click',':checkbox',function(e)
            {

                $.ajax({
                    url: "checkforentry2.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: 
                    {
                        chargetype : $('#ddlchargetype').val() 

                    },
                    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
                    {
                         if(data == "No")
                         {

                         } 

                         else
                         {
                            alert(data);
                            $(this).prop('checked',false);


                         }

                    }

                    });

            });
```

So please tell me how should I do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the context is an object that represents the ajax settings used in the call (`$.ajaxSettings` merged with the settings passed to `$.ajax`).

so here `$(this)` represents the ajax settings

you can add a hack

```
$("#multiselectunittype").multiselect("widget").on('click',':checkbox',function(e){
  var $element=$(this);    
  $.ajax({
           url: "checkforentry2.php",
           type: "POST",
           data:{
                  chargetype : $('#ddlchargetype').val() 
                },
           success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
                      if(data == "No"){

                       }else{
                         alert(data);
                         $($element).prop('checked',false);
           }
         }

        });
    });
```

Or you can use [context](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) option in ajax setting:

```
context: this,
success:fuction(){
  $(this).prop('checked',false);
}
```